# App Store Auto-Renewing Subscription with variable amount

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, payment, subscription

I want a pay-as-you-go offer in my App (auto-renewing subscription, but the price is variable). Is this possible through Apple payments or do I need another payment system?

Comment: No.  The price of in app purchase products is set in App Store Connect to prevent fraud. If the service is delivered through the app then you must use in app purchase. You cannot use a different payment gateway.

Comment: @Paulw11 If the payments are made over a website, is that allowed?

Comment: It is,  but you cannot link to the web site in your app nor provide any details about the website in your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 And I can't just use stripe in the app?

Comment: Not if the service is delivered in the app. You can only use other purchase methods if you are selling goods or services delivered outside the app (pizza or plumbing repairs or something).  Search Epic vs Apple for details

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, thanks. But I could handle the whole registration process (including payments) on a website and mention the registration on the website (but not the payments) in the app?

Comment: If the website collects payments and the app mentions the website (even if you don't mention payment via the website in the app) you will possibly still be rejected.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with Apple payments. You don't need any other payment system. You can read [more](https://medium.com/@johnblanchard_23089/flutter-stripe-apple-google-pay-507ef0390c91) about it. There is [stripe_payment](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment) package for both Google Play Store and Apple App Store.

Comment: But does Apple allow stripe just like that, because this is not the standard payment way you need to use according to the developer guidelines?